# Incorrect random coloured rectangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to display random colors in the GL_POLYGON.

But the colors changes only on minimize and maximize.It picks a different color on maximization and a different color on minimization.But it randomizes the colors as long as i continue minimizing and maximizing

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>

void display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    for( int i = 0; i < 255; i++ )
    {
        glColor3ub( rand(), rand(), rand() );
    }
    glVertex3f( 0.25, 0.25, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.75, 0.25, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.75, 0.75, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.25, 0.75, 0.0 );
    glEnd();

    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRectf( 0.45, 0.25, 0.55, 0.05 );
    glRectf( 0.35, 0.08, 0.65, 0.02 );

    glFlush();
}

void init( void )
{
    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( 250, 250 );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Assignment" );
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glutDisplayFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) only calls your callback when the OS needs your window re-drawn.  If you want more regular calls you need to trigger them yourself via [`glutPostRedisplay()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html):

> ...  When GLUT determines that the normal plane for the window needs to be redisplayed, the display callback for the window is called. ...
>
> ...
>
> GLUT determines when the display callback should be triggered based on the window's redisplay state. The redisplay state for a window can be either set explicitly by calling `glutPostRedisplay` or implicitly as the result of window damage reported by the window system. Multiple posted redisplays for a window are coalesced by GLUT to minimize the number of display callbacks called.

I like to use `glutTimerFunc()` to call `glutPostRedisplay()` periodically:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>

void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    glColor3ub( rand(), rand(), rand() );
    glVertex3f( 0.25, 0.25, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.75, 0.25, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.75, 0.75, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.25, 0.75, 0.0 );
    glEnd();

    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRectf( 0.45, 0.25, 0.55, 0.05 );
    glRectf( 0.35, 0.08, 0.65, 0.02 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 250, 250 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```